# Is it possible to mock custom Angular 2 Material SVG icons for unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, angular-material2

In my app's root component, I am defining custom SVG icons for `md-icon`. When unit testing a component that displays the custom icon I get an error. It seems that the error is likely due to the fact that my root component is not being used/initialized in my child unit test.

Is there a way to mock or add these custom icons (or `md-icon`) when setting up the test module? I would simply define the icons in the component I am testing, but I know other components will need them also.

The error:

```
Uncaught Error: Error in ./CustomerComponent class CustomerComponent - inline template:34:19 caused by: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_rxjs_Observable__.Observable.throw is not a function
```

Full error: [image]

Removing the custom icons from the template solves the error.

---

My template is using the custom icons like this:

```
<md-icon svgIcon="vip">vip</md-icon>
```

And the root component initializes the icons like this:

```
this.iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
    'vip',
    this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/icons/vip.svg') as string,
);
```

I set up the test component like this:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            SharedModule,
            CoreModule,
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
        ],
        providers: [
            {
                provide: Router,
                useClass: class {
                    navigate = jasmine.createSpy('navigate');
                },
            },
            {
                provide: ActivatedRoute,
                useValue: {
                    data: {
                        subscribe: (fn: (value: Data) => void) => fn({
                            customer: CUSTOMER,
                            company: COMPANY,
                        }),
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                provide: UtilityService,
                useClass: UtilityServiceMock,
            },
            // etc...
        ],
        declarations: [
            CustomerComponent,
        ],
        schemas: [
            CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
        ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
}));
```

#### Versions

- Angular 2.3.0
- Material 2.0.0-beta.1

Comment: currently having the same issue with angular 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question:

After much trial/error with items like mocking the `MdIconRegistry` or using `componentOverride()` etc with no luck I no longer use a shared module within my tests.

Instead, I declare the MdIcon component directly in my testing module using a mock version of the class.

```
describe(`CustomerComponent`, () => {
    let component: CustomerComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<CustomerComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                FormsModule,
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                MdButtonModule,
            ],
            providers: [
                OVERLAY_PROVIDERS,
                {
                    provide: Router,
                    useClass: class {
                        navigate = jasmine.createSpy('navigate');
                    },
                },
                {
                    provide: ActivatedRoute,
                    useValue: {
                        data: {
                            subscribe: (fn: (value: Data) => void) => fn({
                                customer: customer,
                                company: COMPANY,
                            }),
                        },
                        params: Observable.of({
                            customerId: customerId,
                        }),
                    },
                },
            ],
            declarations: [
                CustomerComponent,
                // Declare my own version of MdIcon here so that it is available for the CustomerComponent
                MdIconMock,
            ],
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CustomerComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;

        fixture.detectChanges();
    }));


    it(`should exist`, () => {    
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

MdIconMock is simply a blank class that matches the selectors:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    template: '',
    // tslint:disable-next-line
    selector: 'md-icon, mat-icon',
})
// tslint:disable-next-line
export class MdIconMock {
}
```

> Note: Due to TSLint rules that specify the prefix/format of class names/selectors I needed to disable TSLint for this mock.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to use the [`overrideModule`](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/TestBed#overrideModule) method to stub [MdIcon](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/api). The documentation is sparse but I was able to find a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10689) where Angular team members discuss how to override declarations. The idea is to remove the component from the `MdIconModule` so that we can declare our own mock icon component.

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TestedComponent ],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
        SharedModule,
      ],
    })
    .overrideModule(MdIconModule, {
      remove: {
        declarations: [MdIcon],
        exports: [MdIcon]
      },
      add: {
        declarations: [MockMdIconComponent],
        exports: [MockMdIconComponent]
      }
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

The `MockMdIconComponent` is defined very simply

```
@Component({
  selector: 'md-icon',
  template: '<span></span>'
})
class MockMdIconComponent {
  @Input() svgIcon: any;
  @Input() fontSet: any;
  @Input() fontIcon: any;
}
```

I used this approach because I am not importing the Material modules individually and I did not want my test to have to make Http calls to get the svg icons. The `MockMdIconComponent` could be declared in the testing module but I chose to declare/export it in the module override so that I could extract the object into a test helper.

Answer (score 3):

This is a late answer. Just in case anyone come across this, there is an alternative other than OP's solution (which is nice as well):

**Imports MaterialModule using forRoot()**

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [
            TestComponent
        ],
        imports: [SharedModule, MaterialModule.forRoot()],
        providers: [{ provide: Router, useValue: routerStub }]
    });
    TestBed.compileComponents();
```

**Get the injected MdIconRegistry and DomSanitizer**

```
let iconRegistry = TestBed.get(MdIconRegistry);
let sanitizer = TestBed.get(DomSanitizer);
```

**Configure them as you did in normal app**

```
iconRegistry.addSvgIcon( 'some-icon',
sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/img/some-icon.svg'));
```

Comment: FYI, Angular will ask for an Http provider (if not imported with your `SharedModule`) and will download the material icons directly in your test.

Answer (score 2):

building on @Chic's answer, since I have icons everywhere, i made a testbed patch:

```
import {TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {MatIconModule, MatIcon} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

export function PatchTestBedMatIcons() {
  const original = TestBed.configureTestingModule;
  TestBed.configureTestingModule = (moduleDef) => {
    return original(moduleDef)
      .overrideModule(MatIconModule, {
        remove: {
          declarations: [MatIcon],
          exports: [MatIcon]
        },
        add: {
          declarations: [MockMatIconComponent],
          exports: [MockMatIconComponent]
        }
      });
  };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'mat-icon',
  template: '<span></span>'
})
class MockMatIconComponent {
  @Input() svgIcon: any = null;
  @Input() fontSet: any = null;
  @Input() fontIcon: any = null;
}
```

then in your component test simply:

```
import {PatchTestBedMatIcons} from 'src/app/patchTestBedIcons';
PatchTestBedMatIcons();
```